# Whirling Blade and Whip Dagger Interaction

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

How would you rule that this spell and this weapon would interact with each other?

That anyone within 15 feet would be hit along the line, or that it would function as normal?

Answer (score 2):

The spell attacks each creature in the line. The weapon’s reach does not come into play.